# Java Generic <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> vs <K, V extends Comparable<V>>

Tags: java, generics, extends, super

I read the question about [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java). The second answer mentioned

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue( Map<K, V> map )
```

I was confused with the part

```
<K, V extends Comparable<? super V>>
```

Can I explain it as "V has to be subclass of any class which implements Comparable interface" ? Or how should I explain it into words?

Does it equivalent to

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>>
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: More like "V has to be *comparable* with itself or any of its superclasses". This is so you can have `class Animal implements Comparable<Animal>`, and `class Dog extends Animal`, and still sort a collection of `Dog`s. In your latter signature, this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Thanks very much. <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> means  the type T must implement Comparable of T or one of its super classes.           <K, V extends Comparable<V>> means T must implement Comparable of T.